# Why can you cook cake with soda?

Tags: baking, substitutions, soda

I saw a Tumblr post, claiming that you can make a Betty Crocker cake with only a 12 oz can of soda. I tried it this morning and though I haven't eaten it yet, I think it worked.

This is odd to me because many bakers and chemists sell egg substitutes e.g., vegans. Why can a $2 coke can do what many companies fail to sell to a mainstream audience can?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You will need to edit and post a recipe, or at least a link, otherwise nobody will have any idea what you are talking about. Is this one of those recipes where they add a can of soda to a premade cake mix? If so, you could make that cake with plain water and it would still work, the cake mix has all the active ingredients.

Comment: @GdD I assume the carbonation in the soda (and possibly the acid) helps with rising, which plain water wouldn't.

Comment: The cake mix has leavening agents already @Esther, but I'm sure the carbonation doesn't hurt.

Comment: @GdD the acid I mentioned may possibly react with the leavenings in the cake mix, and I've seen seltzer used in matzo balls for its leavening effect. I've similarly seen egg-free cake recipes that rely on baking soda and a bit of vinegar for leavening (which does work!)

Comment: Sounds like you have an answer @Esther.